# Angular $http not resolving in $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http, route-provider

I am trying to display data from a JSON file onto the webpage. My Code

```
angular.module('bioA.configs',['ngRoute'])
//Config routes
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',
    {
        templateUrl: 'list.tpl.html',
        controller: 'BioACtrl',
        resolve: {
            bioAList: ['$http',function($http){
                return $http.get('bioa.json');
            }]
        }
    });
}]);
//Controller to Manage the data
angular.module('bioA.controllers',['bioA.configs'])
.controller('BioACtrl',['bioAList','$scope',function($scope,bioAList){
    console.log(bioAList);
    $scope.samples = bioAList.data.samples;
}]);
angular.module('bioA',['ngRoute','bioA.controllers','bioA.configs','ui.bootstrap']);
```

The $http doesnt seem to resolve.
here is the console output:
[image: Console output]
I am AngularJS noob any help is appreciated :) I am stuck. Why is the resolved object a ChildScope rather than being a promise ?

Comment: Please provide the applicable HTML.

Comment: from your error you get undefined `samples` but not `data`. Sounds like `bioAList` has been created but there is  now `data`

Comment: @onaclov2000 Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3TYikXchG2E7gENQzBf?p=preview)

Comment: this seems to be an async request so you need to listen for a success or failure not just return $http.get('bioa.json');

Comment: @emailnitram I have updated the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3TYikXchG2E7gENQzBf?p=preview) to do that the status returned is 200 on the console, which means the data should be available in the controller(?).

Comment: You don't have to listen for success or failure if you allow the resolve function to take care of the promise. The only problem was the reversed annotations as @hassassin pointed out. See: http://plnkr.co/edit/6X6jUM3h28eKYBPjrSUj?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, your includes are reversed here

```
controller('BioACtrl',['bioAList','$scope',function($scope,bioAList){
```

Should be

```
controller('BioACtrl',['$scope', 'bioAList',function($scope,bioAList){
```

Second, you are trying to access data in your bioAList service before you even fetch it. The correct way to do this is with angular promises. I modified the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzzVzwP8dzwkpmIVYu1R?p=preview) to acheive this access paradigm:

```
bioAList.getSamples().then(function(data) {
    $scope.samples = data.samples;
})
```

EDIT: add the thing that @OdeToCode points out.

Good point! you can just return the $http promise as the service.

```
return $http.get('bioa.json').success(function(data,status){
    return data;
})
```

And access it like you originally had.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can write less code if you avoid using $q. The return values from then or success will be wrapped in a promise. You also don't need to resolve the promise in the controller as that is what the resolve function is designed to do. See:http://plnkr.co/edit/zaOYzlCFKqVYF9ycs9aG?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot!! just fixing the dependency order fixed it. @odetocode Yes I dont think we need to use $q as $http returns a promise after resolve.